# Initialize dataframe with sample datetime values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I saw a few questions on stackoverflow where sample dataframes where provided but the dates where formated as string. Therefore I wondered if there is a way to initialize the `pandas.DataFrame()` in a way to already load the data as datetime object in contrast to formating the pd.Series() after initializing the dataframe, as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['2020-01-01'], ['2020-07-01']], columns=['date'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

How can I initialize the df without needing the last line?

I tried:

```
pd.DataFrame([['2020-01-01'], ['2020-07-01']], columns = ['date'], dtype=pd.datetime)
```

which obviously failed.

Expected output:

```
df['date']
Out[139]: 
0   2020-01-01
1   2020-07-01
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.to_datetime(["2020-01-01", "2020-07-01"])})`?

Comment: @sacuL, ah, so simple, works perfect, thank you. I Just discovered you can also use: `dtype=pd.DatetimeTZDtype(tz='UTC')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solutions for future readers:

```
# by sacuL
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.to_datetime(["2020-01-01", "2020-07-01"])})

# by myself
dtype = pd.DatetimeTZDtype(tz='UTC')
```